# Вместо появления горизонтальной прокрутки растягивается блок

Tags: html, css, overflow

У меня есть блок со свободной шириной (почти до края экрана). Внутри это блока есть другой, с фиксированной шириной, которая может превышать ширину экрана в несколько раз. Вместо того, чтобы растянуть обзавестись прокруткой, первый блок растягивается и растягивает вместе с собой своего родителя и все элементы, находящиеся с ним на одном уровне вложенности.

```css
.parents
{
  width:50%;
}

.wrapper
{
  overflow:auto;
  width:100%;
  background-color:cyan;
  height:200px;
}

.wide-el
{
  width:2000px;
  height:100px;
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="wide-el">
      some content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Исправьте `.parents` на `.parent`

Comment: Вот поидее и ваша ошибка, если я правильно понял суть.

Comment: Это условный код. весь код сюда не поместился бы.
Стоит отметить, что у родителя элемента . parent стоит display:grid, который делит дочерние элементы на фракции (grid-template-columns: 100px 1fr;), где .parent является последним дочерним элементом. Под фиксированный размер .wide-el расширяется всё вплоть до элемента с grid'ом

Answer (score 0):

В общем, помучившись пару часов, я пришёл к выводу, что единицы fr не такие уж универсальные. Всё дело было в них - они растягиваются под ширину содержимого, если оно больше их текущей ширины. пришлось для родителя поставить grid-tempate-columns: 100px calc(100%-100px); Это решило мой вопрос.